# Can't mount external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, external-hdd

i have a problem accessing the data on my external hard drive. I recently did a fresh install but mistakenly left my external hard drive plugged in.

When I tried to access the data on the external HDD, it says "no files" but recognizes that there is 290 GiB of data on it. The HDD is 350GB big.

I checked the drive with Disk Utility and it showed that the hard drive had a bootable flag. So, in the edit partition, I unchecked this bootablity.

Now it won't mount in Ubuntu and now my XP can't recognize it at all, whereas I could access the data on the XP machine before.

In disk utility, it doesn't give me the option to check the bootable box in again and I can't access the data on XP either.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried `sudo fdisk -l` and see if the device is recognized?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should install a utility called *GParted*: `# apt-get install -y gparted`. After it reads the hard drive, you will have the opportunity to right click on the partition and restore the bootable flag. On a side note, the bootable flag should **not** interfere with the ability of Ubuntu to mount the partition.

You should try mounting the system on a LiveCD environment. (The Live CD has *GParted* installed by default.)

It is a Windows XP partition so I will assume that the drive is formatted as an NTFS drive. For the mount issues, at first you should check the output of `# fdisk -cl`. It should return some sort of output like this:

```
root@localdomain:/# fdisk -cl

Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbb28bb28

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        4570    36700160    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            4570        9730    41447425    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            4570        7059    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            7060        9232    17447936   83  Linux
/dev/sda7            9232        9730     3998720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Where the `/dev/sd` something is the partition's identifier. To mount the partition, you will need to create a folder under the `/media` path, it will serve as the mount point. Execute the command `# mkdir /media/external`, then mount the partition with the command `# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/external`, where `/dev/sda1` is the identifier we retrieved from the above command output, and `/media/external` is the folder we just created.

(**Note:** Commands prefixed with a `#` in this answer indicate that execution requires elevated, superuser (`root`) privileges. Under normal circumstances, you will need to prefix all commands with `sudo` to authorize yourself. So `# apt-get install gparted` turns `$ sudo apt-get install gparted`. `#` indicates a root, `$` indicates a normal terminal session.)